# Unity: Prefab parenting in code

Tags: unity-game-engine, gameobject

Let's say I want multiple prefab object called `childTile`, it parenting another single prefab object called `parentTile`. So whenever the `parentTile` rotates, `childTiles` will be rotated around `parentTile`.

Basically this is what I wrote:

```
public GameObject childPrefab;
public GameObject parentPrefab;

void Update()
{
   for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   {
      GameObject clone = Instantiate(childPrefab, /*PsuedoCode: random position*/ , Quaternion.identity)

      clone.transform.parent = parentPrefab;

   }
}
```

The expected result is during runtime, if I rotate `parentPrefab` at the scene, the 10 `childPrefabs` should also rotate. I've tried many ways but failed, unless I manually drag `childPrefabs` to `parentPrefab` on the Hierachy bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you want to `Instantiate` 10 child prefabs on each frame (`Update` is called once per frame).

I think you problem is, that you did not `Instantiate` the parent prefab.

If I take your code, and fix it, it works like a charm for me.

```
public GameObject childPrefab;
public GameObject parentPrefab;

void Start() 
{
    GameObject parent = Instantiate(parentPrefab) as GameObject;

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        GameObject child = Instantiate(childPrefab) as GameObject;
        child.transform.parent = parent.transform;
    }
}
```

This is the result of above code, and I suspect, that's what you want?

[image]

Comment: Thank a lot!! I did not instantiate the parent object. How stupid of me, it took me 4 hours on this problem.